# Possible to get unique browser instances in e2e specs written for protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm using protractor to run some end-2-end tests for an Angular application, and from what I can tell, all the specs I specify in my config file end up sharing the same instance of protractor's `browser`.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but I am also using [http-backend-proxy](https://github.com/kbaltrinic/http-backend-proxy/wiki/Installation-&-Usage#installation) to set up mock responses to my application's ajax calls. This module uses the browser instance, and it seems that setting up mock responses in one spec pollutes the `browser` instance for subsequent specs, causing all the specs to use the mock response strategy defined in the first spec.

Obviously this creates some problems for test isolation.

Has anyone dealt with something similar?

[edit]

I did not find a way to create multiple browser instances, but did find a way to deregister http-backend-proxy responses between tests, which accomplishes the test isolation I was looking for. For future reference to anyone that runs into this same problem, I was using:

`proxy.onLoad.when()`

setups to handle my mock responses. You can deregister these with:

`proxy.onLoad.reset()`

If you place these in `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` blocks, respectively, you can accomplish isolation both between tests within a given spec, and between separate spec files.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow the issue but you may want to look at [feature request #381](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/381).